# Android basic activity call 2 pages with 1 button respectivly found no erros on validate still won't work in AVD

Tags: java, android

Can someone tell me whats wrong?? lost

Thanks,Mike

P.S.

I figured this might work instead of the splash for 1st page.

page1 or activity 1

```
package com.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
public class test1 extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(),test2.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

    }
        });
    }
    }
```

page2 or activity 2

```
package com.test;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class test2 extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
                   }
               }) ;
        }


}
```

Manifiest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".test1"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activity2"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: New Beginner! Just trying to get my code to go back and forth with 2 acvtivties and 2 buttons.

Answer (score 0):

What is really wrong is you posting a question on StackOverflow, asking "Can someone tell me whats wrong??", without even taking the time to describe what symptoms you are experiencing. You are lucky that I am in a pretty good mood right now.

There are at least two problems:

1. Your manifest refers to an `Activity2` that does not appear to exist
2. Your activity `test2` is not defined in the manifest

Comment: I am a total newbie and want just to write some code that is basically 2 screens or activities that refer to each other. My background is HTML and some JavaScript. This is a new world to me.

Comment: Thank you both for taking an interest if I can get it work,It would be a good study aid to advance my understanding.

Comment: @Mike: I apologize for my tone, but it is difficult to help people when you do not know what problem they are experiencing. There are countless tutorials available for Android, free online (just use a search engine). There are a couple of dozen books, many Android open source apps, and all sorts of other resources to take advantage of. You may think it is more expedient to punch code in, then dump the code in StackOverflow and have us debug it, but if you do that, at least take the time to explain what problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @Mike: For example, if you are getting a "Force Close" dialog, use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with the "force close".

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you just created your manifest incorrectly, seems that you have test2 as the class but tell the manifest it's name is Activity2.